# Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /jsp/error.jsp

Tags: java, uri, malformed, malformedurlexception

I am getting an java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /jsp/error.jsp, 
I have already seen lots of questions related to this, none of that helped me.

Here is my full stack trace

```
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /jsp/error.jsp
    at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLStylesheet.flushErrors(XSLStylesheet.java:2248)
    at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLStylesheet.execute(XSLStylesheet.java:628)
    at oracle.xml.xslt.XSLProcessor.processXSL(XSLProcessor.java:364)
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXTransformer.transform(JXTransformer.java:504)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Without your code it is difficult to tell you what your problem is

Comment: `"http://"` (or any protocol you want to use) is missing in front of `"/jsp/error.jsp"`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a protocol (`http://`) and a domain (`www.google.com`) in your URL.

**This is a valid URL**: `https://www.google.com/example.html`

You need to give a valid URL, otherwise you will keep getting a `MalformedURLException`.

Comment: Thanks For suggestion.